# receiving email to my gmail account using actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Please forgive the newbie question. I'm building a form that has a contact us page, in which a user should be able to fill out a form (user_full_name, user_email, subject, message), which when submitted should be sent as an email to my gmail address. I'm currently getting the following error when I try to access the view with the form on it.

undefined method `feedbacks_path' for #<#:0x007f8fefecd020>

below is my code, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? If possible I'd rather change the routes than add a url to the form. Also, want to use a 'match' in the routes to have the url path be 'localhost/contact' instead of 'localhost/feedback'. Does anyone have any ideas?

routes.rb

```
Sample::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :feedback, only: [:new, :create]

  root to: "home#index"
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/privacy_policy', to: 'static_pages#privacy_policy', via: 'get' 
  match '/terms_and_conditions',   to: 'static_pages#terms_and_conditions',   via: 'get'
end
```

Feedback_Controller.rb

```
class FeedbackController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @feedback = Feedback.new
  end

  def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])

    if @feedback.valid?
      FeedbackMailer.new_feedback(@feedback).deliver
      flash[:success] = "We have receieved your message!"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill in all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Feedback.rb

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.columns() @columns ||= []; end

  def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)
    columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)
  end

  column :user_full_name, :string
  column :user_email, :string
  column :subject, :text
  column :body, :text

  belongs_to :user
end
```

view/feedback.new.html.erb

```
<div class="feedback">
  <div class="container">
    <%= form_for @feedback do |f| %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :user_full_name %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_email %>

      <%= f.label :subject %>
      <%= f.text_field :subject %>

      <%= f.label :feedback %>
      <%= f.text_area :body %>

      <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-inverse" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

feedback_mailer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    Name: <%= @feedback.user_full_name %>

    Email: <%= @feedback.user_email %>

    Subject: <%= @feedback.subject %>

    Comments/Question: <%= @feedback.body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

feedback_mailer.rb

```
class FeedbackMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to:   "railstraining09@gmail.com"

  def new_feedback(feedback)
    @feedback = feedback
    mail(from: @user.email, subject: 'feedback.subject')
  end

end
```

Comment: Go through this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email) for an intro.

Comment: You'll need a message form (model+view+controller) to capture the user's message, And upon create, send the email using some kind of background job queue.

Comment: I suggest you read the offical documentation/guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html it guides you through the process, step-by-step setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in developement you could add in app/config/environments/development.rb

```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  # Gmail SMTP server setup
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
  }
```

and give it a try.
You can create instead a file mail.rb in config/environments/ or if you want to use a specific email account for each environment than you will need to write in each 'environments' file (production.rb; test.rb, development.rb) your ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings { options .... }

P.S. I would suggest you to use mandrill/sendgrid etc instead [video](https://gorails.com/episodes/sending-emails-with-mandrill)